# Проблема с SOAP в java

Tags: java, soap

```
try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
                .newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("enc",
                "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("env",
                "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/");

        SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
        SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();

        SOAPElement headerElement = header
                .addChildElement("locale", "", "");
        headerElement.addTextNode("ru");

        SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement("GetClientInfo");
        bodyElement.setPrefix("ns0");
        bodyElement.setAttribute("SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle",
                "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

        SOAPElement paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("params");
        paramsElement.addChildElement("Login").addTextNode("Login");

        message.saveChanges();

        System.out.println("\nREQUEST:\n");
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        String destination = "https://api.direct.yandex.ru/wsdl/v4/";
        SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, destination);

        reply.writeTo(System.out);

        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Ошибка: SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Not Allowed
Что нужно делать?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть какой получается `request`, сравнить с примером: [Протокол SOAP](http://api.yandex.ru/direct/doc/concepts/SOAP.xml)